# onCreate前にEventHandlerで値を変化させるには？

Tags: java, android, kotlin

AndroidでWebView表示の前に`uri`の値を条件によって変更させたいです。

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super<DefaultActivity>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)

        setupUri()

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            val newFragment = WebViewFragment.newFragment(uri!!)

            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.web_view_container, newFragment)
                    .commit()

        }

        getSupportActionBar().hide()

    }

}
```

参考にしたiOSの場合はこうなってます。

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [self registerEventHandlers:[self prefferedEventhandlers]];
}
```

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓呼び出し↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
 override func prefferedEventhandlers() -> [AnyObject]! {
        
        return [
            LSGAdEventHandler(webViewController: self),
            LSGLoginPageEventHandler(webViewController: self),
            LSGOtherEventHandler(webViewController: self)
        ]
        
    }
```

これはviewDidLoadで画面描画する前にEventHandlerを走らせる処理だと思うのですが、onCreateが該当するでしょうか。

Comment: `setupUri()`で`WebViewFragment.newFragment(uri!!)`に渡してる`uri`フィールドに何か値をいれてるように見えるのですが、あってますか？

Comment: urlを読み込む前にフックするのが目的で、
oncreateが走らないとwebviewが生成されず、質問自体が間違っていました。
webviewが持ってるメソッドのonPageStartedでEventHandlerを走らせるので、質問を閉じます。

Comment: 自己解決したようですね。後に同様の問題に遭遇した方の助けになるので、解決した方法を回答として記述していただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

urlを読み込む前にフックするのが目的で、oncreateが走らないとwebviewが生成されず、質問自体が間違っていました。

webviewが持ってるメソッドのonPageStartedでEventHandlerを走らせる方法をとります。

---

*この投稿は [@hai123 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/15143/oncreate%e5%89%8d%e3%81%abeventhandler%e3%81%a7%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e5%a4%89%e5%8c%96%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af#comment13758_15143) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*